# IntelliJ Hibernate facet without hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot Data JPA for my project and would like to add the Hibernate facet. However, this seems to require the use of hibernate.cfg.xml to use for the path property in the facet to work. This completely defeats the purpose of Spring Boot and the auto configury shenanigans it provides. My workaround is to use the JPA facet with Hibernate as the default provider, but I would like to use the Hibernate facet instead. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151230 and the linked issues.